# How can I use my Intel GPU in a headless X server?

Tags: gpu, x-server, intel-graphics, opengl

When OpenGL rendering something using my normal X server, `intel_gpu_top` shows me that `Render/3D/0` is being used (to about 60%). When doing the same rendering on a dummy X server (the *xserver-xorg-video-dummy* package on Ubuntu), the GPU does not get used. Instead, the CPU is maxing out, but rendering is 2 or 3 times slower.

Is it possible make use of my GPU in a headless setup?

Answer (score 0):

you can use Hashcat, a password recovery program, which has a benchmarking option. https://hashcat.net binary
`apt install p7zip-full`
`wget https://hashcat.net/files/hashcat-6.2.6.7z && 7z x -o* hashcat-6.2.6.7z`
`hashcat-6.2.6/hashcat-6.2.6/hashcat.bin -b -m 1000` (--benchmark --hash-type)